# Два вопроса. sealed и throw

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет. Что бы не плодить мелкие темы есть два вопроса.

**Первый про sealed.**

Этот оператор используется что бы не могли наследоваться от класса.
Но на примере Unity, у них класс Application был sealed, а потом в новых версиях сделали просто class Application.

Как понимаю сделали они для того, что бы могли расширять класс Application.

Вопрос: нужно ли вообще использовать sealed и в каких случаях? Если в любой момент потом может пригодится расширение класса. Например у меня сейчас есть класс SteamManager (для работы с Steam API), мне его делать sealed ?

Складывается ощущение что ставят sealed, а потом как придет время убирают его редактирую класс и нарушая солид.

**Второй про throw и Debug.LogError.**

Зачем и когда вообще использовать Debug.LogError, если можно всегда throw ? Я просто не пойму логику выбора. Например у демонстрации класса API Steam, у них идет инициализация и в случаи провала вызывается Debug.LogError где пишется ошибка, НО почему не вызывать throw ? Точно так же будет писаться ошибка в консоль.

Comment: Сделали бы вы 2 отдельных вопроса

Comment: Вы хотите получить два ответа, при этом отвечающий получит баллы как за 1 ответ. Это нечестно по отношению к отвечающему - смысл ему напрягаться в два раза больше? Пишите свои вопросы каждый отдельно.

Comment: @Mit "Серьезный дяденька", вы пришли на ресурс, у которого есть свои правила, уважайте окружающих и следуйте этим правилам! Вы задаете "Вопрос", это не форум с темами, а база "Вопрос-ответ". Так задавайте вы четко сформулированный, 1, вопрос! А хамство свое, оставляйте у себя дома и хамите близким. Минус от меня за ваше поведение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, `sealed` нужен для того, чтобы запретить наследование. А `const` или `readonly` для того, чтобы запретить изменения. Можете подумать, когда нам нужно убирать эти слова.

При наследовании мы используем  **абстрактный** класс, описывающий интерфейс и **общие детали**, и классы **наследники**, реализующие какие-то компоненты (**уточнают абстрактый**).

В вашем примере класс SteamAPI должен быть запечатан. SteamApi - конкретная вещь, поэтому наследование для него не имеет смысла.